# Controls.RichTextBox vs. Forms.RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

In my Project i currently need a RichTextBox control for highlighting some Text whilst editing it (some kind of Syntax highlighting).

What I tried was to put a System.Windows.Controls.FlowDocument in a RichTextBox. But There are two of them!

One (Windows.Forms.*) can be applied to the form, the other (Windows.Controls.*) cannot, but the second one can handle FlowDocuments.

Any hints how to solve my mess?

Other methods, to be able to track a Textblock, and change its formatting depending on user input would be also welcome!

Comment: One is for WPF the other is for Winforms.

Comment: They are not interchangable? Was Microsoft so intelligent to write two complete independent classes for the same functionality?

Comment: Same functionality for two different technologies and no, they're not interchangeable. What you can do is create a WPF user control that contains the WPF `RichTextBox` then use it from your WinForms app using an `ElementHost`

Comment: Fortunately i just began the project, so i moved from Forms to WPF, thanks for the information!

Comment: The WPF RichTextBox is almost totally unusable. I'd recommend using WindowsFormsHost to host the WinForms version in any WPF application.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [ICSharpCode](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30936/Using-ICSharpCode-TextEditor). This has full syntax highlighting and a wealth of documentation. Using this will be much easier than writing your own editor.

However, if you require RichTextBox features, you could override the RichTextBox itself and use a timer to hightlight text based on the matches from a regex say. This second aproach will need a buffer strategy to avoid highlighting/editing the entire RichTextBox control...

I hope this helps.