# Does not contain definition after reference has been added

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am VERY new to C# so it is possible this is a really easy problem, but even after all my reading I cant find a way to add the definitions Visual Studio 2010 wants despite having added the using statements and the references on the MSDN docs page for each expression.

My Error:

```
System.windows.forms does not contain a definition for document
```

I added the reference "presentationframework" based on something I was reading on the Microsoft site. Thanks to some of the comments below I discovered I was apparently mixing two different ways to get text from the box. All I need to be able to do is paste content into the textbox, and get the contents of the box when i press a button. Can someone tell (or better yet show) me definitively how to do this without mixing strategies?

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class HackController : Form
{
    ArrayList ipList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList acctList = new ArrayList();
    int myAcct = 0;
    string myIp = "";
    public HackController()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void sync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string data = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd).Text;// ERROR HERE
        string[] lines = Regex.Split(data, "\n");
        Regex ipMatch = new Regex(@"\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+");
        Regex acctMatch = new Regex(@"#\d+");
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {
            foreach(Match m in ipMatch.Matches(line))
            {
                ipList.Add(m);
            }
            foreach( Match m in acctMatch.Matches(line))
            {
                acctList.Add(m);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's `.Split` also use native struct `string` for strings

Comment: Try remove the `using System.Windows.Forms;`, the `rtb` should be `System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox` not `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox`

Comment: @YuliamChandra, I tried doing what you suggested, but it did not fix my issue. If I remove .Forms I run into errors with my pulic partial class.... I will update my code to include the entire class

Comment: Well, my point was [`WinForm's RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't have `Document` property... unless you use [`WinControl's RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You were right, that was my bad for not including all of my code the first time.

Comment: It's not clear to me if your problem has been solved or not. If not, just to try to make it more clear, there are two different Windows .Net technologies for desktop programs: WinForms and WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation). You seem to have managed to mix them together in your program, and that's not a good idea unless you really know what you are doing. There is a RichTextBox control in each technology. The one for WinForms does not have a Document property. Adding an extra "using" statement doesn't change that fact, it just confuses things more.

Comment: See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407974/controls-richtextbox-vs-forms-richtextbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a (rather strange) sample showing one way to display data in a WinForms RichTextBox control. (Sorry, but it's the only sample I can find in my programming because I'm usually using Developer Express WinForms controls instead of the basic .Net ones.)

But first, to be 100% sure you are not mixing WinForms and WPF, make sure that when you create the project you select WinForms as the project template type (not WPF). And when you drag-and-drop the RichTextBox control from the Visual Studio toolbox onto your form, make sure it is the WinForms RichTextBox, not the WPF one.

You can check this by looking in the .Designer.cs file, and find the definition of the RTB control created by the Visual Studio designer. It should look something like this:

```
     this.rtbResults = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();

     ...
     ...

     // 
     // rtbResults
     // 
     this.rtbResults.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
     this.rtbResults.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 52);
     this.rtbResults.Name = "rtbResults";
     this.rtbResults.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(640, 133);
     this.rtbResults.TabIndex = 17;
     this.rtbResults.Text = "";

     ...
     ...

  private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox rtbResults;
```

The important thing being that it says "System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox", not something else.

OK, here's my strange example, which displays the results of a Scrabble cheater program:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Method to display the results in the RichTextBox, prefixed with "Results: " and with the 
  /// letters J, Q, X and Z underlined.
  /// </summary>
  private void DisplayResults(string resultString)
  {
     resultString = UnderlineSubString(resultString, "J");
     resultString = UnderlineSubString(resultString, "Q");
     resultString = UnderlineSubString(resultString, "X");
     resultString = UnderlineSubString(resultString, "Z");

     rtbResults.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi " + "Results: " + resultString + "}";
  }


  /// <summary>
  /// Method to apply RTF-style formatting to make all occurrences of a substring in a string 
  /// underlined. 
  /// </summary>
  private static string UnderlineSubString(string theString, string subString)
  {
     return theString.Replace(subString, @"\ul " + subString + @"\ul0 ");
  }
```

This uses Microsoft's proprietary Rich Text Format, but RichTextBox can also use straight text. And this demo only writes to the RTB, it doesn't read from it, although doing that is fairly trivial.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The solution to my problem was: string dataFromBox= rtb.Text;